# Compression File

Tags: compression

I have a X bytes file. And I want to compress it in block of size 32Kb, for example.
Is there any lib that Can I do this?

I used Zlib for Delphi but I just can compress a full file in new compressed file.

Tranks  a lot,
Pedro

Comment: Which programming language do you intend to code?

Comment: Since you mention Delphi I assume you're targeting Windows. I'm not sure that fits your needs but NTFS supports transparent file compression out of the box. It already splits compressed files in small blocks so that random access performance don't suffer to much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a simple header to determine block boundaries? Consider this:

1. Read fixed amount of data from input into a buffer (say 32 KiB)
2. Compress that buffer with a "freshly created" deflate stream (underlying compression algorithm of ZLIB).
3. Write compressed size to output stream
4. Write compressed data to output stream
5. Go to step 1 until you reach end-of-file.

Pros:

1. You can decompress any block even in multi-threaded fashion.
2. Data corruption only limited to corrupted block. Rest of data can be restored.

Cons:

1. You loss most of contextual information (similarities between data). So, you will have lower compression ratio.
2. You need slightly more work.